# Java Rex is not giving the output as expected

Tags: java, regex

```
networks[0]/site[9785d8e8-9b1f-3fc0-8271-6e32f58fb725]/equipment/location[144ae20e-be33-32e2-8b52-798e968e88b9]
```

The objective is to get the 9785d8e8-9b1f-3fc0-8271-6e32f58fb725 from above string. I have written the regex as below. But its giving the output as "location".

```
.*\\/([^\\/]+)\\[.*\\]$
```

Could any one suggest me the proper regex to get the 9785d8e8-9b1f-3fc0-8271-6e32f58fb725 from above string.

Comment: Yes it always enclosed in first [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `site\[(.+?)\]`. See the [test](https://regex101.com/r/fDu51s/1).

P.S. You current expression is actually doing the following:

1. Pass whatever `.*`
2. Unless you encounter `/`
3. then capture any sequence after `/` not containing: `\`, `/`
4. which in turn is followed by `[]` with whatever content straight away and residing at the very end of the string.

So the only matching part is `location`

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this regex:

```
^[^/]+/[^\[/]*\[|\].*
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sWxBu/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `^[^/]+/[^\[/]*\[`: This pattern matches text before first `/` then `/` followed by text till it gets next `[`
- `\].*`: Matches `]` and everything afterwards

**Code:**

```
String s = "networks[0]/site[9785d8e8-9b1f-3fc0-8271-6e32f58fb725]/equipment/location[144ae20e-be33-32e2-8b52-798e968e88b9]";

String r = s.replaceAll("^[^/]+/[^\\[/]*\\[|\\].*", "");
//=> "9785d8e8-9b1f-3fc0-8271-6e32f58fb725"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
^networks\[\d\]\/site\[([^]]+)\].*$
```

It will match

- the literal string networks[]/site[
- followed by your id
- followed by ] and arbitrary stuff

You can then extract your ID from the first capturing group.